# Crash when repeatedly calling RegionIntersection (and/or Mesh functions)

Tags: regions, mesh, crash, intersection

My kernel (v13.1.0 Windows 64-bit) crashes when repeatedly (~9 times) calling `Region` functions like `RegionIntersection` upon simple `Polygon`.

Take for example these simple input polygons:

```
polygons = {Polygon[{{-6,298},{98,298},{98,198},{-6,198}}],Polygon[{{202.,163.36904761904762},{171.,163.},{171.,100.},{2.,100.},{2.,0.},{171.,0.},{171.,-24.},{202.,-44.66666666666667}}],Polygon[{{370.6,0.},{502.,0.},{502.,100.},{358.1666666666667,100.},{339.,165.},{300.,164.53571428571428},{300.,-44.125}}],Polygon[{{248.82501070724447,-87.90184472304296},{202.00000237873843,-56.68517250403892},{202.,-44.66666666666667},{202.,173.36975621072258},{300.,174.5364228773892},{300.00000220959214,-55.91747503407568},{300.,-55.917476415070766}}],Polygon[{{202.,277.22222270743714},{202.,173.36975621072256},{300.,174.5364228773892},{300.,249.9999966555138}}],Polygon[{{300.,-200.},{300.00000220959214,-55.91747503407568},{248.82501070724447,-87.90184472304296},{202.00000237873843,-56.68517250403891},{202.,-200.}}],Polygon[{{400.,222.22222222222223},{400.,194.},{498.,194.},{498.,300.},{400.,300.},{400.,257.77777777777777},{480.,200.}}],Polygon[{{202.,277.22222222222223},{202.,296.},{300.,296.},{300.,250.}}],Polygon[{{400.,222.22222222222223},{480.,200.},{400.,257.77777777777777},{390.,264.99999031574845},{390.,225.00000438132946}}],Polygon[{{390.,225.00000438132946},{390.,264.99999031574845},{300.,330.},{150.,350.},{120.,300.},{202.,277.22222240762164},{202.,296.},{300.,296.},{300.,250.00000687306255}}]};
```

They resemble:

> [image]

While some functions behave fine...

```
RegionDisjoint @@ polygons

>>> False
```

as does `RegionIntersection` when called *once* upon any individual pair of Polygons:

```
RegionIntersection @@ polygons[[{2, 4}]]

>>> MeshRegion[{{202., 163.36904761904762}, {202., -44.666666666666664}}, {Line[{{1, 2}}]}]
```

Alas, calling `RegionIntersection` *repeatedly* causes it to crash after about ~9 calls!

```
RegionIntersection /@ Subsets[polygons, {2}];

(kernel exits without notice)
```

The crash occurs only when repeatedly calling `RegionIntersection` upon actually intersecting pairs. It runs fine when acting only upon the `36` disjoint region pairs:

```
RegionIntersection /@ 
    Select[Subsets[polygons, {2}], RegionDisjoint @@ # &]

>>> {EmptyRegion[2], ... }
```

It also runs fine when run upon any individual intersecting pair:

```
badPairs = Select[Subsets[polygons, {2}], Not[RegionDisjoint @@ #] &];

i = 1

(* below runs fine when re-evaluated for every i *)
RegionIntersection @ badPairs[[i++]]
```

Yet, it crashes when mapped onto even only the first `7` of the `9` pairs!

```
RegionIntersection /@ badPairs[[;; 7]]

(kernel crash)
```

Maddeningly, I can reduce the *likelihood* of this crash by insert `Echo` statements into the loop:

```
(* crashes ~4/5 times *)
Do[
    Echo["Stephen pls fix"];
    RegionIntersection @ pair,
    {pair, badPairs}
 ]

(* crashes never (slower Echo) *)
Do[
    Echo @ RegionIntersection @ pair,
    {pair, badPairs}
 ]
```

This isn't merely *slowing* the loop, since replacing `Echo` with `Pause[1]` (with and without `ClearSystemCache[]`) still causes a crash.

Since `RegionIntersection` sometimes returns a `MeshRegion` (an irritation in itself, since other times it returns a `Polygon`), I suspect this crash occurs due to communication with an [FEM](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) module. Although it seems insane to think `7` calls with incredibly simple `Polygon` could overload a local module!

Is there an obvious mistake I am making leading to this unstable behaviour? Is this otherwise a core Mathematica bug? I have seen complaints online that the meshing facilities (especially with functions like `RegionDifference` is unstable).

Comment: What makes you believe this is an issue with FEM? You are not calling any FEM functions...

Comment: Crashes should always be reported to WRI, because otherwise they can not fix them.